# Why is isJavaLetterOrDigit deprecated?

Tags: java, deprecated

Why is the method `isJavaLetterOrDigit` in `java.lang.Character` deprecated?

The docs say that the method `isJavaIdentifierPart` should be used instead, but don't indicate why. The documentation for the two methods is otherwise identical. Googling the subject did not turn up any explanation.

In fact, a source code search shows that nowadays, one just calls the other, so there is no difference in behavior. Was it just deprecated because it had a more confusing name? Seems like a rather strange decision.

```
@Deprecated
public static boolean isJavaLetterOrDigit(char ch) {
    return isJavaIdentifierPart(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old (deprecated) name does not properly reflect what the implementation actually does; e.g. it accepts characters that are neither letters or digits.  I imagine this would have resulted in a few "bug" reports and support requests from confused developers.  IMO, that is the most likely reason that they took the (significant) step of creating a new method and deprecating the old one.

(Other reasons proposed by @HuiZheng are valid points at an intellectual level, but NOT sufficient to justify deprecating a method.  The Java folks DO NOT go around changing APIs purely on the basis of good API design principles.  Deprecating methods makes work for developers, and Oracle does not want to alienate companies who pay those programmers' salaries.  Java has gained so much traction in the Enterprise world because of its reputation as a stable platform!)

Anyway, deprecating this method seems (to me) like an obvious and sensible API design decision taken for the right reasons.  Either way, our opinions are moot.

Answer (score 5):

*Reason 1:*

A good API name should be abstract enough(but not too abstract). `isJavaLetterOrDigit` is too implementation-oriented. If you that's what you really want, use `isLetterOrDigit` instead.

*Reason 2:*

A good API name should exactly specify its purpose and should be implemented correctly. `isJavaLetterOrDigit` is misnomer because it actually allows non-letterOrDigit character such as "_" or "$".

*Reason 3:*

A good API name should be harmonic with others. `isJavaIdentifierPart` is consistent with other APIs such as`isJavaIdentifierStart`, `isUnicodeIdentifierPart`, `isIdentifierIgnorable`.

Lastly, just because there is no difference in behavior between these two APIs doesn't mean they are identical. Misleading API names poison your code. Furthermore, always dump the deprecated APIs ASAP, as they will eventually(or highly possibly) be dumped by library providers.

Comment: They can't 'be dumped by library providers', for binary compatibility reasons.

Comment: @EJP I know for compatibility reason the deprecated APIs are usually kept for some time. But in the long run, library provider may choose to break that compatibility. Anyway, we don't want to take that risk.

Comment: @HuiZheng - Based on past history, the method won't be removed.  It would not be in either Oracle or its (paying) customers interests to do this.  The documentation says that this *could* happen ... but I predict that it *won't*.  (Or at least, it won't unless Oracle can provide reliable tools to automatically upgrade old code at the source code AND bytecode level.)

Comment: @Stephen Rewriting bytecode to call the new methods would actually be pretty easy as long as it isn't using reflection (and I don't think reflection was introduced until after this was deprecated, anyway). But that's too much effort for something where you might as well just leave it in. It's not like they're worried about library bloat with a JRE that contains 18k and counting classes. Anyway, seeing as they still have legacy methods that date back to before Java was even publicly released, they're almost certainly never going to remove stuff like this.

Comment: @Antimony - on the face of it, yes ... in simple cases like this.  But you've also got to consider the impact on the rest of the toolchain; e.g. debuggers, profilers.  And there are also implications for reflective code ... and security managers.  It all adds up to a pretty complicated problem.

Comment: That's right, Java is a very, very backwards-compatible language, and JDK rarely removes deprecated methods, but it's still not 100% backwards-compatible(e.g. http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/post1.0/converting/incompatibleChangesAWT.html). Besides, we don't want `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` stuff everywhere.

Comment: @HuiZheng - You are right.  There was significant breakage from 1.0 to 1.1.  This was justified on the basis that there wasn't a lot of code developed using Java 1.0 ... and the changes were really necessary. There have been occasional breakages since then too, but AFAIK they all involved fixing behaviour that was buggy; i.e. that plainly contradicted the javadocs.